# Условия и функции Си, не выполняется условие для Men

Tags: c, if, условия

Задача на Си: Написать программу, которая запрашивает у пользователя пол,
рост и вес, а затем анализирует соотношение роста и веса, выдавая соответствующие рекомендации. Вот мой код. Подскажите, почему, когда вводишь `women`, программа работает правильно, а для `Men` цикл не выполняется, а работает так же, как для `Women`?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Header.h"

    int main()
    {

        char gender[6];
        float height, weight;
        printf("Enter your gender:\n");
        scanf("%s", gender);//Ввели пол
        printf("Enter your height:\n");
        scanf("%f", &height);//Ввели рост 
        printf("Enter your weight:\n");
        scanf("%f", &weight);//Ввели вес

        if (gender[0] == 'W', 'w')
            Women(height, weight);
        else if (gender[0] == 'M', 'm')
            Men(height, weight);
        else
            printf("Error");



    return 0;
}
```

файл с функцией:

```
int Women(float height, float weight)
{
    if ((height - 110)>weight)
    {
         printf("Get fat!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((height - 110)<weight)
    {

         printf("lose weight!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else

            printf("Normal\n");

    return 0;
}
int Men(float height, float weight)
{

    if ((height - 100) > weight)
    {
        printf("Get fat!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if ((height - 100) < weight)
       {

        printf("lose weight!\n");
        return 1;
       }
    else

        printf("Normal\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Заголовочный файл .h

```
int Women(float height, float weight);
int Men(float height, float weight);
```

Comment: И что по-вашему делает вот это `if (gender[0] == 'W', 'w')`? Откуда у вас возникла идея использвания запятой вот таким вот образом?

Comment: Спасибо AnT, нашел ошибку , идея была сравнивать первый элемент массива на наличие заглавной или маленькой буквы W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (gender[0] == 'W', 'w')
```

Итак, согласно правилам языка C, мы имеем дело с оператором "запятая", т.е. выполняется сравнение `gender[0] == 'W'`, после чего возвращается значение `w`, которое, согласно правилам того же языка, рассматривается как `true`. Независимо от результата сравнения.

```
if (gender[0] == 'W' || gender[0] == 'w')
```

вот так будет ближе к тому, что вы хотели...